# Is need separate Transaction Manager between JMS and JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I faced with problem when error in JDBC transaction cause return JMS-message to queue, I guess so. It means that some message are being processed again.

My app has next configuration:

1. I have configured JtaTransactionManager like this:

```
...
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
....
```

2. And I has configured JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer like this:

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, ....) throws NamingException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setSessionTransacted(true);
    container.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    ....
    return container;
}
```

In my case, when I receive a JMS message, in my code logic happens org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException. I handle exception via try-catch block and I expect everything will be fine. But in this time, as I see, message return to queue and it being processed again. This behavior isn't reproduce, if in my code happens other Exception, like as IllegalStateException/RuntimeException.

And I suppose that error in JDBC transaction causes broke JMS transaction despite the fact I handle exception.

Let me know, is it correct that I use one transaction manager for JPA and JDBC?
Or I need two different implementations for my DataSource and JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer?

Also, if I can produce more information, I will.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the code where the exception is created ? How do you handle your exception ? How did you configure your JDBC and your Datasource ? do you use JDBC Template ?